# Prove connected graph minus one vertex still connected.

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a connected graph with at least two vertices. Prove that G has a vertex v such
that if v is removed from G (along with all edges incident with it), the resulting graph is also
connected.

**Hint**: Consider a spanning tree and one of its leaves.

So I know that (using the hint), if the graph is a tree, one of such vertices that has this feature would obviously be a leaf vertex. The problem is, this problem doesn't specifically state to prove this for Trees, but for graphs in general. Any help here as to where to start would be appreciated.

Comment: The hint manifestly gives you the solution.

Comment: Are you saying that all I have to do is prove that the connected graph can be treated as a spanning tree, then use the hint to show that such a vertex can just be a leaf?

Comment: If a subgraph is connected, then the graph itself is connected.

Comment: Find a spanning tree in your graph, what happens if you remove one of the leaves from the spanning tree?

Comment: No. Do you know that a graph $G$ is connected if and only if it has a spanning tree $T$? Then, if you remove a leave of the spanning tree, what it remains is a tree (say $T'$) spanning the resulting graph (say $G'$).

Comment: okayokay, so I can say, because G is connected, then it has a spanning tree T. If a leaf is removed from a spanning tree, the tree is still connected, and thus the graph G is still connected.

Comment: @MichaelBurr you mean *if a subgraph on all vertices of a graph is connected...*

Comment: @wbrugato Yes, this is the way to solve. It was easy, wasn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $G$ is connected, it has a spanning tree.
You can delete any leaf $v$ from the spanning tree and the graph still has a spanning tree, so is still connected.

Answer (score 3):

**Without using the hint:** Choose a vertex $u,$ and then choose a vertex $v$ at maximum distance from $u.$ To see that $G-v$ is connected, consider any other vertex $w.$ Since $G$ is connected, there is a path from $u$ to $w$ in $G;$ the *shortest* such path does not pass through $v,$ so it is a path in $G-v.$ (Of course this is more or less the way you would prove that a tree has a leaf.)